# Crosshair feature of Zing Chart is leak CPU

Tags: javascript, angular, zingchart

When I enable the crosshair feature in my chart, everything works OK in Chrome 56, but when I upgraded Chrome to 57 (even chrome 58 and ZingChart 2.6.0 now), The CPU usage is always above 25% when hovering the chart such as to see a crosshair. When I have 2 charts, CPU usage goes up to 99% and the browser slows and crashes soon after.

I tried disabling all features to see what was the cause of this issue, and when I disable the crosshair, CPU usage is normal again. And if I disable everything but the crosshair feature, the same CPU hogging effect is observed.

The only way to free the resources is by terminating the tab.

Here is my code:

```
var dataChart = {
  id: "ShSDbePYhAxC",
  data: {
    type: "area",
    "crosshair-x": {
      "plot-label": {
        text: "The %t Series has a value of %v."
      }
    },
    gui: {
      behaviors: [
        {
          id: "Reload",
          enabled: "none"
        }
      ],
      contextMenu: {
        customItems: [
          {
            function: "zingAlert()",
            id: "zingAlert",
            text: "zing Alert"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    item: {
      angle: -30
    },
    legend: {
      "background-color": "white",
      "border-color": "black",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border-width": 2,
      layout: "1xauto",
      padding: "10%",
      x: "12%",
      y: "90%"
    },
    plot: {
      alphaArea: 1,
      aspect: "spline",
      "bar-width": "15px",
      "contour-on-top": false,
      lineWidth: "2px",
      stacked: true,
      marker: {
        visible: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        visible: false
      }
    },
    plotarea: {
      "margin-bottom": "23%",
      "margin-left": "dynamic"
    },
    "scale-x": {
      item: {
        angle: -30
      },
      labels: [
        "Name0", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"
      ]
    },
    "scale-y": {
      label: {
        "font-size": "15%",
        text: "Number Of Visitors"
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        text: "Text A",
        values: [11111, 222222, 3333333, 444444, 55555]
      },
      {
        text: "Text B",
        values: [6666, 777777, 88888, 99999, 12121212]
      }
    ]
  },
  height: 550,
  output: "canvas",
  width: "100%",
}
```

Comment: have you asked [here](https://www.zingchart.com/support/) per chance? Oh, never mind, I see they use stack overflow for there support - good luck

Comment: already send a ticket to them :) thanks @JaromandaX

Comment: All good. They claim SO is how to get support so I guess they'll be along shortly

Comment: Hey, you can directly email to support@zingchart.com, we always respond within 24 hours or less. @Jaromanda X we offer support directly via multiple channels. Stack Overflow, our website, twitter, email. We always enjoy talking to our users.

Comment: Can you replicate this on plnkr.co and post a link here? Also, are you using System.js to load zingchart?

Comment: im using angular-cli and i will make this on plnkr.co as soon as i finish my task >.< , thanks @mike-schultz :). I have seen you guys open my ticket, thanks Derek Fletes. :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have been leaning to believe this may be a chrome and Angular issue. To confirm this can you revert your zingchart version to an older version like v2.2.2. You can reach this version through the cdn at the following links

Root directory:
http://cdn.zingchart.com/2.2.2/

ZingChart.min:
http://cdn.zingchart.com/2.2.2/zingchart.min.js

Modules:
http://cdn.zingchart.com/2.2.2/modules/

If the problem still happens its a browser and Angular issue and we know where to focus our efforts. If the problem goes away it's directly a ZingChart issue.

Comment: Oh, zingChart 2.2.2 is so good, not leak CPU anymore, thanks :) So i will use version 2.2.2 until you guys update new version of ZingChart. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thank you for confirming. So we updated crosshairs in versions 2.4.0 and above. We will have to take a look at why newer versions of chrome trigger the issue. I'm not sure what we changed but I will email you for more details. This post is more informational for anyone else running into issues.